# rectangle Isnt showing up java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I try to have a rectangle show up on my JPanel, but when I run it, it doesn't work.  My code in my canvas class is:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(80, 350, 400, 250);
}
```

Comment: What if you call `super.paintComponent(g);` at the end of the method instead of the beginning?

Comment: There can be many ways why this code can fail. Forgetting to add the canvas, method not being triggered, the element being super tiny and covered by other components... You'll really have to paste more code for this to be solvable, otherwise we're guessing in the dark :)

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] when asking a question. We don't know the context of how the panel is used on the frame. My best guess is that the size of the panel is (0, 0) so the rectangle can't be painted in that space.

Comment: @MickMnemonic,  The point of invoking `uper.paintComponent(g)` as the first statement is to make sure the background of the component is painted so you have a clean background to paint on. If you add that statement at the end of the method then you will just paint over any custom painting and all you will be left with is the background.

Comment: @camickr, it's been a while I've used Swing, but that depends on the opacity of the component(s), right?

Comment: @MickMnemonic well if the component is transparent, then it doesn't matter where the statement is, since the background won't be painted. But if it is opaque, then it will paint over top. Either way, your suggestion doesn't make sense. Read the tutorial on `Custom Painting`. I provided a link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
g.fillRect(80, 350, 400, 250);
```

Based on the above code the size of your panel needs to be 480 x 600, otherwise the rectangle can't be completely displayed on the panel.

When you do custom painting you also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your class to return the desired size of the panel, otherwise the size may be (0, 0), depending on the layout manager you use, and therefore there is nothing to paint.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.